# make - Get path to file without filename

Tags: makefile, compilation, gnu-make

I have in my Makefile a rule to get all src files:

```
CFILES := $(shell find ./ -type f -name '*.c')
```

How can I get only the Path to the file (without the filename) of the `CFILES`.

For example:

`./drivers/fb/fb.c` becomes `./drivers/fb`

`./stivalle/stivalle.c` becomes `./stivalle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the GNU make section on [File Name Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html).

So you can write:

```
DIRS := $(dir $(CFILES))
```

This gives you paths with a trailing slash.  If you want to remove the trailing slash, you can use:

```
DIRS := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(CFILES)))
```

This will also give you duplicates if you have multiple source files in the same directory.  If you want only one instance of each directory you can use:

```
DIRS := $(sort $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(CFILES))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`dirname` is your friend. (dont't forget `man dirname`)

eg

```
$ dirname /opt/foo/bar.json
/opt/foo
```

Comment: How can I use that on the ``CFILES``?